# Possible to run Python 2.7 and Python 3 in same notebook?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776744/run-python-unit-test-with-python-2-7-and-3-x).  I have to support Python 2.7 and 3.

I have some code that is written in python 3.  This works great on my python 3 install (anaconda for win7 + jupyer-notebook).  I need to unit test my code under a python 2.7 environment.

Is there an easy way to setup a 2.7 environment on my anaconda setup without clobbering my working install?  It would be really cool to be able to run python 2 under a 3 notebook using a magic command!

Comment: you can have python 2 and 3 installed at the same time, their packages are managed separately

Comment: You can definitely have both python 2 and python 3 environments set up under Anaconda, but a _notebook_ (Jupyter) only currently attaches to a single kernel, and thus can only run a single version at a time. If you can edit the Python 2 code, use `six` as suggested in the question you linked to so that your code runs in a single Py 2 or Py 3 environment. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Please give example.

Comment: thanks for the tips!  I maintain this package:  https://github.com/twdb/sonde3  I have an example notebook, and unit tests 
 (nosetests).  My unit tests work fine in python3, but I need to run this in a 2.7 environment to bug fix and run the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Download anaconda for both the version

Step 2: open  .bashrc

Step 3: add the path to new anaconda you have installed 
for eg:

`export PATH="/home/paras/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Step 4: Now there will be 2 export path one for python 2 and one for python 3.

Comment the one which you don't want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have python 2.7 and 3 on the same system. Use the shebang on the top of your script to make the distinction between the 2 as necessary. These discussions should also address some of your concerns -

[How to install both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7)

[How do I run python 2 and 3 in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912063/how-do-i-run-python-2-and-3-in-windows-7/17245543#17245543).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating 2 conda virtual environment and choose the kernel you want your jupyter notebook to run on. You should install `nb_conda_kernels` so that your environments are automatically recognized as different kernels. Follow this procedure (after having installed anaconda/miniconda):

- Outside any environment, install nb_conda_kernels: `conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels`
- Outside any environment, install jupyter: `pip install jupyter`
- Create a virtual environment and activate it
- In the environment, install jupyter: `pip install jupyter`
- Inside any environment, run `jupyter notebook`
- Choose the environment by clicking on the kernels tab

https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels

Answer (score 0):

The following is the steps to create a Anaconda virtual environment to ease your testing.

1. Open a `Anaconda Prompt` window.
2. Type `conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda` to create a new
   virtual environment named `py27`. You can create any new virtual environment with different version of Python, e.g. `Python=3.6`, for testing purpose.
   [image]
3. Launch the root `Jupyter Notebook` to start Jupyter server.
   [image]
4. Open your Python 3 notebook with the codes to be tested, from your Jupyter dashboard browser.
5. From menu bar, → Kernel → Change kernel → `{select target env}` for your code testing 
    
   [image]

Hope this help.